# Segmentation Fault on return statement

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, return, malloc

I am using tmx parser to parse a file, I have a 2D array called `map1`,
if I declare it static i.e. `int map1[w][h]` the program runs fine.
But on declaring it as dynamic (via malloc & 2D pointer),  I get segmentation fault:

```
int main()
{
    Tmx::Map map;
    int width,height; 
    map.ParseFile("new.tmx");
    if (map.HasError())
    {
        cerr<<"Error loading map:"<< map.GetErrorText();
        return 1;
    }
    const Tmx::Layer* current_layer = map.GetLayer(0); 
    width = current_layer->GetWidth();;
    height = current_layer->GetHeight();
    cout<<"\n\n"; 

//    int map1[height][width];          
    int **map1;
    map1=(int**)malloc(height*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
        map1[i]=(int*)malloc(width*sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            map1[j][i] = current_layer->GetTileId(i, j);

    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
        {     
            cout.width(3);
            cout<< map1[i][j]<<" "; 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

i tried to debug via gdb , an i get to know that "return statement" is the cause of error,

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  malloc_consolidate (av=0xb7e83420 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4151
#1  0xb7d4bbab in _int_free (av=0xb7e83420 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4057
#2  0xb7eed9df in operator delete(void*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0xb7eeda2b in operator delete[](void*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0xb7fcf0eb in Tmx::Layer::~Layer() () from /home/user/Documents/TMX/tmxparser-master/build/libtmxparser.so.1
#5  0xb7fc9b3f in Tmx::Map::~Map() () from /home/user/Documents/TMX/tmxparser-master/build/libtmxparser.so.1
#6  0x08048d4a in main () at main.cpp:69
(gdb) frame 6
#6  0x08048d4a in main () at main.cpp:69 
69      return 0;
```

Comment: You need to recompile because of the "Source file is more recent than executable" warning. Don't use `malloc` in C++, use standard containers like `std::vector`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch   here 2d matrix is involved so to keep stuff simple , i have temporarily avoided vector; are you trying to say that malloc is reason for segfault ? can you explain more regarding malloc in context of this code ?

Comment: You may also want to use one-dimension arrays, add access them with `arr[i*width+j]` for matrix element (i,j)

Comment: `to keep stuff simple , i have temporarily avoided vector` This is first mistake. Learn vector and you will find things so much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop should iterate up to `height`, not `width`.